# Flask not writing to file

Tags: python, file, flask

I've been meaning to log all the users that visit the site to a file.
Using Flask for the backend.
I have not been able to get python to write to the file. Tried keeping exception handling to catch any errors that might be generated while writing. No exceptions are being raised.
Here is the part of the blueprint that should write to file.

```python
from .UserDataCache import UserDataCache
udc = UserDataCache()

@main.route('/')
def index():
    s = Suggestion.query.all()
    udc.writeUsertoFile()
    return render_template('suggestions.html', suggestions = s)
```

Here is the UserDataCache class:

```python
from flask import request
from datetime import datetime

class UserDataCache():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def writeUsertoFile(self):

        try: 
            with open("userData.txt","a") as f:
                f.write(str(datetime.now()) + " " + request.remote_addr + " " + request.url + " " + request.headers.get('User-Agent') + "\n")
        except IOError,e:
           print e
        return
```

Comment: What occurs if you don't catch the exception?

Comment: Does not write to the file in either case.

Comment: You might be better off using the `logging` module: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/errorhandling/#logging-to-a-file

Comment: @xssChauhan then try raising one yourself to see if this piece of code is even called.

Comment: @greut The code is being called. Print calls nested in the try block are working just fine.

Comment: @xssChauhan then try a different path, e.g. `/tmp/userData.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using an absolute path and verifying the permissions on that file. Something like /tmp/UserData.txt or another absolute path should work. The web server's user is what needs the permission to write to the file (www-data if you're using apache2 with Ubuntu, or check your web server's conf file to verify).

As far as why you're not seeing the exception you're catching, I see you're using print. If you're calling the app using a web browser, you'll need to send the error to something else, like a log file or flash it to the browser, or raise an error so it gets logged in the web server error log.

Answer (score 0):

Is your python file name begins with uppercase? If so, try to modify it into lowercase.

I just came into the same problem and copied the exactly same code into two .py file. The only difference is their file name, one being 'Flask_test.py' and another being 'flask_for_test.py'. It's weird that 'Flask_test.py' works just fine except it cannot write into any file and 'flask_for_test.py' works perfectly.

I don't know whether the format of the file name has an effect on the function of python but using lowercase file name works for me.

By the way, all other solutions I found didn't work.